# Using gettext in a php project - Only one language translated

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I am trying to translate a webpage to several languages. However, I can only make gettext work for spanish.

I am using this code:

```
$lang = "de_DE";
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) $lang = $_GET['lang'];
putenv("LC_ALL=$lang");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain("messages");
```

If I set $lang="es_ES" the strings get translated to spanish, but if I set $lang="de_DE" the translation doesn't work, I only see the default english version.

I think it may be something about my computer locale (I use Windows in spanish). I am working on Windows (using Wamp localhost) and I don't know whether I have to install something more and, if so, how to do it.

In case I have to do it, will it work in my online hosting without installing anything there?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setlocale() has issues in Windows that is mentioned in PHP's official documentation itself:

> The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If
>   you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS or Apache
>   on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while
>   a script is running, though the script itself never called
>   setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different
>   threads of the same process at the same time, changing the
>   process-wide locale using setlocale().
>
> Windows users will find useful information about locale strings at
>   Microsoft's MSDN website. Supported language strings can be found in
>   the » [language strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and supported country/region
>   strings in the » [country/region strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Mainly what you need to realize is that many PHP functions are wrappers over *ix OS program APIs. So they will work well in linux and other compatible OSes - not that well in Windows.